# How to add sharepoint searchbox in pagelayout and select the scope, "This site"?

Tags: search

I created a custom pagelayout. I would like to add the sharepoint searchbox inside the pagelayout. I would like to set also the default search scope to "This Site".

**UPDATE**

This is the solution:

```
<%@Register TagPrefix="SearchWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>

                                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    AllowPersonalization="false" 
                                    FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
                                    title="<%$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,LayoutPageZone_MainZone%>" 
                                    id="MainZone" orientation="Vertical" 
                                    QuickAdd-GroupNames="Search" 
                                    QuickAdd-ShowListsAndLibraries="false">

                                    <ZoneTemplate>
                                        <SearchWC:SearchBoxScriptWebPart ID="SearchBoxScriptWebPart1" DefaultDropdownNodeId="1004" UseSiteCollectionSettings="true" EmitStyleReference="false" ShowQuerySuggestions="true" ChromeType="None" UseSharedSettings="true" TryInplaceQuery="false" ServerInitialRender="true" runat="server" _WebPartId="{2243C4B0-F63F-4573-B39E-3A60BA773508}" />
                                    </ZoneTemplate>
                                </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to configure the current search site settings in site administration then configure the searchbox webpart to use this settings.

All details you can find here: 
Configure properties of the Search Box Web Part in SharePoint Server 2013 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576963.aspx